# Numerical Linear Algebra Norms of Matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading Holger Wendland's Numerical Linear Algebra and am looking through the exercises of Chapter 2.

Here is my question:

> Consider the matrix $A=uv^T$ for $u \in \mathbb{R^m}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Show that 
>   $\|A\|_2 = \|u\|_2\|v\|_2$.

I am wondering how to prove this for the case where $m = n = 2$ and for the case where $m = n$.

So far I have been trying to use the definition of the Euclidean norm, that $\|u\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |u_i|^2}$ (same for $v$).

*Is it true that* $\|uv^T\|_2 = \|u\|_2\|v\|_2$?

I've taken multiple real analysis courses but my memory fails me in this regard. The last one I took was two years ago.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true.
Consider this definition of 2-Norm: $\Vert A \Vert_2=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA})$, where $\lambda_{max}$ denotes largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$. 
If both $u$ and $v$ are not zero, then the **only** non zero eigenvalue of $A^TA$ is  $\Vert u\Vert^2_2 \Vert v \Vert_2
^2$ since $$(A^TA)v^Tu=\Vert u\Vert^2_2 \Vert v \Vert_2
^2v^Tu.$$
Hence $\Vert A \Vert_2=\sqrt{\Vert u\Vert^2_2 \Vert v \Vert_2
^2}=\Vert u\Vert_2 \Vert v \Vert_2
$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\|A\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|\le 1 } \|Ax\|_2= \sup_{\|x\|\le 1 } \|uv^Tx\|_2 = \sup_{\|x\|\le 1 } |v^Tx| \cdot \|u\|_2 
= \|v\|_2 \|u\|_2
$$